# How can I fix HTTP ERROR 500 on nginx + varnish server

Tags: nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am running 2 wordpress websites on digitalocean droplet. One website is working absolutely fine.

But on another website When I am logged in to wordpress admin then it works fine. But when I am not logged in, then `HTTP ERROR 500` occurs.

both websites nginx and varnish configuration is same.

Here is NGINX virtual host configuration:

```
server {

    listen 8080;

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /home/user/example.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    include hhvm.conf;


    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    access_log        off;  

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;


    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|woff|eot|ttf|svg|mp4|webm)$ {
            access_log        off;
            log_not_found     off;
        expires 1M;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        }

}
```

Here is `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`

```
# Redirect to Nginx Backend if not in cache
backend default {    
    .host = "127.0.0.1";    
    .port = "8080";
}

import std;

include "lib/xforward.vcl";
include "lib/cloudflare.vcl";
include "lib/purge.vcl";
include "lib/bigfiles.vcl";        # Varnish 3.0.3+
#include "lib/bigfiles_pipe.vcl";  # Varnish 3.0.2
include "lib/static.vcl";

acl cloudflare {
    # set this ip to your Railgun IP (if applicable)
    # "1.2.3.4";
}
acl purge {
    "127.0.0.1";
}

# vcl_recv is called whenever a request is received 
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts == 0) {        
        if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {            
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =  req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;      
        } else {            
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;        
        }    
    }     
    if (req.http.X-Real-IP) {         
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Real-IP;    
    } else {        
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;    
    } 
    # Serve objects up to 2 minutes past their expiry if the backend
    # is slow to respond.
        set req.grace = 120s;

        set req.backend = default;

        if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {        
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";        
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Port = "80";        
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Host = req.http.host;    
        } 

    # This uses the ACL action called "purge". Basically if a request to
    # PURGE the cache comes from anywhere other than localhost, ignore it.
        if (req.request == "PURGE") 
        {if (!client.ip ~ purge)
            {error 405 "Not allowed.";}
            return(lookup);}

    # Pass any requests that Varnish does not understand straight to the backend.
        if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD" &&
                req.request != "PUT" && req.request != "POST" &&
                req.request != "TRACE" && req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
                req.request != "DELETE") 
        {return(pipe);}     /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */

    # Pass anything other than GET and HEAD directly.
        if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
            return(pass);
        }      /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */

    # Pass requests from logged-in users directly.
        if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
            return(pass);
        }      /* Not cacheable by default */

    # Pass any requests with the "If-None-Match" header directly.
        if (req.http.If-None-Match) {
            return(pass);
        }

    # Force lookup if the request is a no-cache request from the client.
        if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
            ban_url(req.url);
        }
        return(lookup);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
# This is otherwise not necessary if you do not do any request rewriting.
    set req.http.connection = "close";
}

# Called if the cache has a copy of the page.
sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        ban_url(req.url);
        error 200 "Purged";
    }

    if (!obj.ttl > 0s) {
        return(pass);
    }
}

# Called if the cache does not have a copy of the page.
sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        error 200 "Not in cache";
    }
}

# Called after a document has been successfully retrieved from the backend.
sub vcl_fetch {
    # make sure grace is at least 2 minutes
    if (beresp.grace < 2m) {
        set beresp.grace = 2m;
    }

    # catch obvious reasons we can't cache
    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    }

    # Varnish determined the object was not cacheable
    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Not Cacheable";
        return(hit_for_pass);

    # You don't wish to cache content for logged in users
    } else if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wp-postpass_|wordpress_logged_in_|comment_author|PHPSESSID") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Session";
        return(hit_for_pass);

    # You are respecting the Cache-Control=private header from the backend
    } else if (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private";
        return(hit_for_pass);

    # You are extending the lifetime of the object artificially
    } else if (beresp.ttl < 300s) {
        set beresp.ttl   = 300s;
        set beresp.grace = 300s;
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES:Forced";

    # Varnish determined the object was cacheable
    } else {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
    }

    # Avoid caching error responses
    if (beresp.status == 404 || beresp.status >= 500) {
        set beresp.ttl   = 0s;
        set beresp.grace = 15s;
    }




    # Deliver the content
    return(deliver);
}

sub vcl_pass {
    return (pass);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Debug    
    remove resp.http.Via;    
    remove resp.http.X-Varnish;    

    # Add a header to indicate a cache HIT/MISS    
    #if (obj.hits > 0) {        
    #   set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";        
    #   set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;        
    #   set resp.http.X-Age = resp.http.Age;        
    #   remove resp.http.Age;    
    #} else {        
    #   set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";    
    #}    

    # Remove some headers: PHP version
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;

    # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
    unset resp.http.Server;

    # Remove some heanders: Varnish
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;


    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_error {
    set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set obj.http.Retry-After = "5";
    synthetic {"
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>"} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>Error "} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</h1>
            <p>"} + obj.response + {"</p>
            <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
            <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Varnish cache server</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            "};
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_init {
    return (ok);
}

sub vcl_fini {
    return (ok);
}
```

I did not understand what is causing 500 error. Please guide me how can I fix this issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked nginx logs? like error_log? I see that access_log is off. Enable it. Check the logs. Both error_log and access_log for that site. See what exactly is shown in the logs when you access the website as a regular user (not logged in).

Comment: I have already checked error_log and access_log. both has nothing any issues..

Comment: When a 500 error is shown the web server is supposed to log that error into the error_log file if the logging is configured. So I am not sure how can you get a 500 error and see nothing in the logs. Are those two websites on the same droplet ?

Comment: yes, both website are in same droplet. 
error_log has below repeated logs
` 7784#0: *2866 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/body/0000000001, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"`

and access_log just showing requested page os and browser info

Comment: is php-fpm configured the same for both sites? Are you using ip:port for php-fpm or sockets? Try having each site with its own php-fpm configuration for example. What you could do also would be to try to disable varnish caching for the problematic site (just to see if the error is related to varnish or nginx) but the way it sounds, the 500 error is most probably returned by nginx. What you're seeing in the logs is an warning not an error and it's related to the directive client_body_buffer_size in nginx which controls the size of that buffer.

Comment: php-fpm is not configured on the server. HHVM is used instead of the php-fpm and it is same for both websites.